# Animation: specify speed, not time

Tags: jquery

I have a draggable element `$myElement` with `revert: true`. Now specifying `revertDuration` will determine the time the reverting animation will take to complete.

My problem is that the speed of the animation will vary greatly depending on how far `$myElement` is dropped from the original location.

Is there a way of specifying the *speed* of the animation (as opposed to the *total time*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `position` plugin for jQuery UI found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

You can get offset of the draggable element. Or simply use:

```
var x = $myElement.offset().left
var y = $myElement.offset().top
```

Solution which comes to my mind:
Save position of the element when `start` event of draggable object is fired. Then do the same when 'stop' event occurs and `animate` the element back to starting offset. The difference in offsets is a line which its length will be proportional to the time required to travel back.

```
var x,y;
$myElement.draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        x = $myElement.offset().left;
        y = $myElement.offset().top;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // count the length of the line from starting point 
        // and trigger back animation 
    }
});
```

You can try to set revert duration when `stop` event is called to avoid `animate` but I don't know if it make it before revert animation.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "revertDuration", 1000 );
```